# Selecting Properties from Objects 2 layers down in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic, javascript-objects

So here's what I am working with:

```
var Data = [Obj, Obj, Obj]
var Obj = {
   string1: 'string',
   string2: 'another string',
   string3: 'different string',
   object: {
      prop1: 'property',
      prop2: 20
   }
   numeric1: 300
}

var SecondObj = {
   string1: '',
   string2: '',
   string3: '',
   prop1: '',
   prop2: undefined,
   numeric1: undefined
}
```

I need to reach the `prop`s in `object` while dynamically sorting through both `Data` and `Obj` at the same time:

```
for (var d in Data) {//iterate through Data entries
    for (var item in SecondObj){// iterate through first-level 
         if (Data[d].hasOwnProperty(item)){
             SecondObj.item = Data[d][item]
         }
         else if (Data[d]['object'].hasOwnProperty(item)){
             //select the prop of object, which is a property of Obj
             //then set that as the value of the matching property of the SecondObj
         }
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different ways of selecting these properties, but they are all throwing errors.  I obviously can't use `'.item'` (obvious, but I tried it anyways to be sure), and I can't use `+ '.' + item`. Just at a loss for selectors, I'm pretty sure.  Quick help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
else if (Data[d]['object'].hasOwnProperty(item)){
    SecondObj[item] = Data[d]['object'][item]
}
```

Comment: That is in array notification. `object` is an object, not an array, so it has no [item]; the property would be at .item, not [item]

Comment: Hold on `d` is the array index so `Data[d]` is an `Obj` and `Data[d]['object']` is also an object and `item` is going to be `prop1` so `Data[d]['object']['prop1']` should work no?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. It does work. There are some naming conventions that crossed between some test data and the name of an object. Thank you, sir!

Comment: All things are sorted, and the person responsible for that bit of test data has been sacked.